# Как удалить дубликаты массива List

Tags: java, android

Имеется `List` массив типа `Integer`, пробовал использовать библиотеку org.apache.commons:commons-lang3, но тут такая проблема:

```
if(help_array.size() != 0){
    for(int i=0; i<help_array.size()-1; i++){
        for(int j=i+1; j<help_array.size(); j++)
            if(help_array.get(i) == help_array.get(j)){
                help_array = ArrayUtils.remove(help_array, j);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Заранее спасибо.

Comment: `List withoutCopies = new ArrayList<>(new HashSet(originalList));`?

Comment: И код лучше текстом. Скринами код не читаем и неиндексируем

Comment: @ЮрийСПб на счет кода вас понимаю, но мне нужно было показать проблему, в следующий раз буду дополнительно и текстом.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ну сохраните ваш список в сет. И он сам уберет все дубликаты.

Это для примера код:

```
List<Integer> help_array = new ArrayList<>();
help_array.add(1);
help_array.add(1);
help_array.add(2);
help_array.add(3);
help_array.add(3);
help_array.add(4);
help_array.add(4);

for (Integer item : help_array) {
    System.out.print("[ " + item + " ], ");
}
System.out.print("\n");

Set<Integer> set = new HashSet<>(help_array);

for (Integer item : set) {
    System.out.print("[ " + item + " ], ");
}
```

Вывод:

Первый список:

```
[ 1 ], [ 1 ], [ 2 ], [ 3 ], [ 3 ], [ 4 ], [ 4 ]
```

Сет:

```
[ 1 ], [ 2 ], [ 3 ], [ 4 ]
```

P.S. Единственное если вы будете использовать HashSet с сложными моделями позаботьтесь о том, чтоб корректно переопределить hascCode() и equals()